# Dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu 12.04 irst, ubuntu not booting (black screen)

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi

I'm trying to dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 on amy new Asus Zenbook U500VZ with 2x 128 GB ssd in raid0 using Intel Rapid Storage Technology (Windows preloaded).

After a bit of trial and error I finally got Windows working and Grub and Ubuntu installed. But when I chose Ubuntu to boot in Grub I barely see the Ubuntu logo with the dots then I get just a black screen (tried adjusting the screen-brightness as suggested on similar threads) and I hear the drum sounds but then nothing happens.

This is what I did:
I turned off Secure Boot, CSM, Fast Boot and then installed windows in EFI/GPT,  turned off Hibernate in Windows and installed Ubuntu. Since it didn't show the "alongside windows 8" option I tried install it manually in this order after the windows partition.

- 200mb for grub where I told Ubuntu to place the bootloader
- about 8 GB for swap
- 15 GB for '/'
- the rest ~60 GB for '/home'

I then ran Boot Repair and got Grub to load and I have no issue with loading Windows 8.

I don't know what else to do.

Boot-repair gave me this for troubleshooting:
*link removed due to link-limtis see link in edit but with /6180438/*

### EDIT:

Tried reinstalling GRUB2 by following this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal
 but it didn't work:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/mapper/isw_dagfijbabd_RAID0SYS6
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Attempting to install GRUB to a partitionless disk or to a partition.  This is a BAD idea..
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

now grub won't work either. All i get is a GRUB repair prompt...

### EDIT2:

I did a complete reinstall of both OS from scratch. And got windows and grub working again. This time I also get the black screen when trying to load Ubuntu from GRUB but now after a couple of minutes I get this message in a prompt:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args for (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
Alert!  /dev/disk/by-uuid/[a hard drive uuid] does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Looks like it doesn't load the right partition but why?

### Edit 3:

Ran boot-repair again and the black screen is back without the output mentioned above in EDIT2.

Could it be an issue with the NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M? It doesn't show in the system details on the live USB. Is there a way to install drivers from the live USB?

this is the new boot-repair link:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6184097/

### Edit 4:

I tried to install the latest Nvidia driver using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

without result....

### Edit 5:

Also tried setting the boot line to `nomodeset`, `no splash`, `nvidia.modeset=0` and `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024x32`still a black screen with the drumsound.

### Edit 6:

If it helps this is my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod efi_gop
  insmod efi_uga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='(hd4,gpt7)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb4c455f-c123-4c54-abbd-d6217a6c2737
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd4,gpt7)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb4c455f-c123-4c54-abbd-d6217a6c2737
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=10
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-31-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd4,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb4c455f-c123-4c54-abbd-d6217a6c2737
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-31-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=fb4c455f-c123-4c54-abbd-d6217a6c2737 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-31-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-31-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd4,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb4c455f-c123-4c54-abbd-d6217a6c2737
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-31-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-31-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=fb4c455f-c123-4c54-abbd-d6217a6c2737 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-31-generic
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-29-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd4,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb4c455f-c123-4c54-abbd-d6217a6c2737
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic root=UUID=fb4c455f-c123-4c54-abbd-d6217a6c2737 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-29-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd4,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb4c455f-c123-4c54-abbd-d6217a6c2737
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-29-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic root=UUID=fb4c455f-c123-4c54-abbd-d6217a6c2737 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###

menuentry "Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root B6F8-C530
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bkpbootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root B6F8-C530
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
}
### END /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

and this is my `/etc/default/grub`

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

### EDIT 7

I got ubuntu installed and working. By using the 12.04.03 alternate installer with this modification. [http://]cirrus[.]ucsd[.]edu[/]~pierce[/]fix_ubuntu_usb[/]. Then I booted up and installed updates and nvidia drivers and I'm back to blackscreen! How do I get rid of the nvidia drivers?

Comment: If you hear the Drum Sound, press FN & Cursor right. Will you see now the Login Screen?

Comment: "I then ran Boot Repair and got Grub to load and I have no issue with loading Windows 8." then, what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is getting Ubuntu to load from Grub.

Comment: no, that did nothing...

Comment: What architecture of Ubuntu did you used?

Comment: amd64 not the alternative though but the regular one